# Data exchange between Java threads

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I need to make 2 java threads data exchange. One thread, i. e. Producer, is producing data, second thread, i. e. Consumer, processing it. I need processing to be blocking, i. e. Producer shall wait till its data will be processed. I'm planning to use it later with multiple Consumer/Producer threads, but decided to start with a kind of mvp/prototype.
The problem is, that I cannot imagine the technique to implement this. I tried first, to create Consumer with BlockingQueue for incoming data, with method to put the data in this queue. Producer calls this method placing data in the queue, then waits till data processing will be completed. Consumer is constantly polling the queue to detect incoming data, and process the data as it arrives. To signal the Consumer that data has been processed, I use Semaphore in the data class. Here's the code sample that implements this scenario:

```
import java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.Semaphore;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

class Adder
{
    Integer a, b, res;
    Semaphore processed = new Semaphore(0);

    Adder(int a, int b)
    {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
        this.res = null;
    }

    int getA()
    {
        return (a);
    }

    int getB()
    {
        return (b);
    }

    int getRes()
    {
        return (res);
    }

    void compute()
    {
        res = a + b;
    }

    Semaphore getProcessed()
    {
        return (processed);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return ("Adder: a=" + getA() + ", b=" + getB() + ", result " + (res == null ? "is undefined yet" : getRes()));
    }
}

class Consumer implements Runnable
{
    BlockingQueue<Adder> requests = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();

    boolean processRequest(Adder adder) throws InterruptedException
    {
        boolean processingResult = false;
        requests.add(adder);
        processingResult = adder.getProcessed().tryAcquire(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        return (processingResult);
    }

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        System.out.println("Consumer thread started");
        while (!Thread.interrupted())
        {
            try
            {
                Adder adder = requests.poll(100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
                if (adder != null)
                {
                    adder.compute();
                    adder.getProcessed().release();
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                }
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e)
            {
                System.out.println("Consumer thread interrupted");
                break;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Consumer thread completed");
    }
}

class Producer implements Runnable
{
    Consumer consumer;

    Producer(Consumer consumer)
    {
        this.consumer = consumer;
    }

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        System.out.println("Producer thread started");
        while (!Thread.interrupted())
        {
            Adder adder = new Adder((int) (Math.random() * 20), (int) (Math.random() * 20));
            System.out.println("New request generated: " + adder);

            try
            {
                if (consumer.processRequest(adder))
                {
                    System.out.println("+ Request has been processed: " + adder);
                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.println("- Request processing failed: " + adder);
                }
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e)
            {
                System.out.println("Producer thread interrupted");
                break;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Producer thread completed");
    }
}

public class ThreadsDataExchange
{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException
    {
        Consumer consumer = new Consumer();
        Producer producer = new Producer(consumer);
        Thread consumerThread = new Thread(consumer);
        Thread producerThread = new Thread(producer);

        consumerThread.start();
        producerThread.start();

        Thread.sleep(3000);
        System.out.println("Interrupting threads");
        producerThread.interrupt();
        producerThread.join();
        consumerThread.interrupt();
        consumerThread.join();
    }
}
```

But in this case, as I need to limit the waiting time, there could be a situation, when Producer would get a timeout waiting for processing, assumes data has not been processed, but data will be immediately processed by the Consumer at the same time.

So, as another approach, I thought to use 2 queues, for incoming and processed messages, but as the real queue might be quite large, it would take a long searching for the processed message in the resulting queue. Then I have the third option to use a kind of SynchronizedMap, or ConcurrentHashMap, but it shall be polled as well, which, I suppose, will result a heavy load. Yet another way to do that I was thinking about, is to use java.util.concurrent.Future, but also not sure how to use it for synchronous/blocking execution.

The question is: how to do that task in Java? Is there some pattern/classes for it? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a queue in which the producer writes to and the consumer consumes from which is what you already have in place. However you can synchronise the producing/consumption to/from this queue with a lock.
You could try using a ReentrantLock: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.html

Also would recommend starting threads with an ExecutorService: https://dzone.com/articles/executor-framework-in-java-take-control-over-your-1

Here is an example:

```
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock;
import java.util.concurrent.*;
import java.util.Queue;
import java.util.ArrayDeque;
import java.util.Random;

public class Main {
    private static final class Producer implements Runnable {
        private final ReentrantLock lock;
        private final Queue < Integer > queue;
        private final Random random = new Random();

        public Producer(ReentrantLock lock, Queue < Integer > queue) {
            this.lock = lock;
            this.queue = queue;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("Running producer in thread " + Thread.currentThread());
            while (true) {
                lock.lock();
                try {
                    System.out.println("Producer has the lock");
                    // Produce data here
                    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                        int randomNumber = random.nextInt(100);
                        System.out.println("Producing " + randomNumber);
                        queue.add(randomNumber);
                    }

                    Thread.sleep(2000);
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                    System.out.println(ex);
                } finally {
                    System.out.println("Producer letting go of the lock");
                    lock.unlock();
                }

                try {
                    // Sleep here so this thread doesn't re-acquire the lock immediately
                    Thread.sleep(100);
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                    System.out.println(ex);
                }
            }
        }
    }


    private static final class Consumer implements Runnable {
        private final ReentrantLock lock;
        private final Queue < Integer > queue;

        public Consumer(ReentrantLock lock, Queue < Integer > queue) {
            this.lock = lock;
            this.queue = queue;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {

            System.out.println("Running consumer in thread " + Thread.currentThread());

            while (true) {
                lock.lock();
                try {
                    System.out.println("Consumer has the lock");

                    while (!queue.isEmpty()) {
                        System.out.println("Consuming " + queue.poll());
                    }
                    Thread.sleep(2000);
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                    System.out.println(ex);
                } finally {
                    System.out.println("Consumer letting go of the lock");
                    lock.unlock();
                }

                try {
                    // Sleep here so this thread doesn't re-acquire the lock immediately
                    Thread.sleep(100);
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                    System.out.println(ex);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int capacity = 10;
        ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock();
        Queue < Integer > queue = new ArrayDeque();

        Producer producer = new Producer(lock, queue);
        Consumer consumer = new Consumer(lock, queue);

        ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);

        service.submit(consumer);
        service.submit(producer);

        service.shutdown();

    }
}
```

Note that we are synchronising access around the queue, therefor the queue itself does not need to be thread safe as we are guaranteeing access to it will be thread safe with the lock.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, I would have a look at an ExecutorService. You can use the submit to receive a future and wait for completion; either synchronously or asynchronously.

https://www.baeldung.com/java-executor-service-tutorial